# C HTTP sockets closing prematurely and apparently giving read errors

Tags: c, sockets, http, server, asyncsocket

**td;lr: trying to echo "Hello World" to an HTTP client but getting issues with the socket closing too soon and mysterious read errors from wrk benchmark tool.**

I am trying to make a simple "Hello World" HTTP server with the [picoev](https://github.com/kazuho/picoev) event loop library but the client/peer connection is dropping too soon and wrk benchmark tool returns read errors for whatever reason I'm not aware. This is the code I'm using:

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netinet/tcp.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/uio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include "picoev.h"


#define HOST 0 /* 0x7f000001 for localhost */
#define PORT 8080
#define MAX_FDS 1024 * 128
#define TIMEOUT_SECS 10

char buf[1024];
ssize_t response;
int listen_sock;


static void close_conn(picoev_loop* loop, int fd)
{
  picoev_del(loop, fd);
  close(fd);
}

static void write_callback(picoev_loop* loop, int fd, int events, void* cb_arg)
{
  // check whether neither events nor timeouts are present
  if ((events & PICOEV_TIMEOUT) != 0) {
    /* timeout */
    close_conn(loop, fd);

  } else if ((events & PICOEV_READ) != 0) {
    /* update timeout, and read */
    picoev_set_timeout(loop, fd, TIMEOUT_SECS);
    ret = read(fd, buf, sizeof(buf));


    if (ret == 0 | ret == -1) {
      close_conn(loop, fd);
    }

    else {
      write(fd, "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nContent-Type: text/html\r\nContent-Length: 13\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\nHello, world!", ret);
      close_conn(loop, fd);
    }

  }
}

static void accept_callback(picoev_loop* loop, int fd, int events, void* cb_arg)
{
  int newfd = accept4(fd, NULL, NULL, SOCK_NONBLOCK | SOCK_CLOEXEC);
  if (newfd != -1) {
    picoev_add(loop, newfd, PICOEV_READ, TIMEOUT_SECS, write_callback, NULL);
  }
}

int main(void)
{
  picoev_loop* loop;

  /* listen to port */
  listen_sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
  setsockopt(listen_sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, 1, sizeof(1));
  struct sockaddr_in listen_addr;
  listen_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
  listen_addr.sin_port = htons(PORT);
  listen_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(HOST);
  bind(listen_sock, (struct sockaddr*)&listen_addr, sizeof(listen_addr));
  listen(listen_sock, 1000000);

  /* init picoev */
  picoev_init(MAX_FDS);
  /* create loop */
  loop = picoev_create_loop(60);
  /* add listen socket */
  picoev_add(loop, listen_sock, PICOEV_READ, 1, accept_callback, NULL);
  /* loop */
  while (1) {
    // Picoev async call to write etc..
    picoev_loop_once(loop, 10);
  }
  /* cleanup */
  picoev_destroy_loop(loop);
  picoev_deinit();

  return 0;
}
```

Curling with `curl http://0.0.0.0:8080/ -v` returns:

```
*   Trying 0.0.0.0...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to 0.0.0.0 (127.0.0.1) port 8080 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: 0.0.0.0:8080
> User-Agent: curl/7.52.1
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Content-Type: text/html
< Content-Length: 13
* transfer closed with 13 bytes remaining to read
* Curl_http_done: called premature == 1
* stopped the pause stream!
* Closing connection 0
curl: (18) transfer closed with 13 bytes remaining to read
```

or the following after trying to benchmark thousands of concurrent connections a few times after another:

```
*   Trying 0.0.0.0...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* connect to 0.0.0.0 port 8080 failed: Connection refused
* Failed to connect to 0.0.0.0 port 8080: Connection refused
* Closing connection 0
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 0.0.0.0 port 8080: Connection refused
```

and `wrk -t1 -c400 http://0.0.0.0:8080/` returns all errors being read:

```
Running 10s test @ http://0.0.0.0:8080/
  1 threads and 400 connections
  Thread Stats   Avg      Stdev     Max   +/- Stdev
    Latency     0.00us    0.00us   0.00us    -nan%
    Req/Sec     0.00      0.00     0.00      -nan%
  0 requests in 10.08s, 9.05MB read
  Socket errors: connect 0, read 249652, write 0, timeout 0
Requests/sec:      0.00
Transfer/sec:      0.90MB
```

I don't understand if the problem is either the socket closing too soon, the response (ret) being incorrect, zombie fd's not being killed or a combination of them. Trying to strace the program doesn't give any valuable info as to where the issue lies, just a lot of *epoll_wait*'s. I've already tried many HTTP response variations to no avail and as you can see I'm trying to kill any zombie or erring fd as soon as necessary but either I'm doing it wrong or the problem lies elsewhere. Can someone help me pinpoint the issue where it belongs?

Comment: I do not have an answer but try using wireshark.

Comment: If you want to implement HTTP, why not use [facil.io](http://facil.io) (I'm the author)? it comes with HTTP built in and you can go straight to writing your app (instead of authoring the HTTP layer).

Comment: @Myst thanks for that, it looks neat and great but for the *extreme* performance required for this use case I can't consider facil.io. I will surely look into it for less demanding applications though!

Comment: @GRC solved but that's a good idea next time I have to debug nagging issues like this.

Comment: @J.Doe, thank you for looking it over. If you're looking for faster solutions that might save you some coding hours, you can look at [the latest TechEmpower Benchmarks](https://tfb-status.techempower.com) and pick something that's been tested to work (facil.io will limit pipelined requests for security concerns, so please ignore that result)... P.S. as for performance, it's faster than nginx on my machine :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this line of code:

> `write(fd, "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nContent-Type: text/html\r\nContent-Length: 13\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\nHello, world!", ret);`

You use `ret` for the third parameter of your call to `write()`. This parameter is used to indicate to `write()` how many bytes should be written.

However, `ret` was used to store the result of a call to `read()`. Thus, there is no relationship between the value passed to `write()` and the size of the message you want to send.

Fix this by initializing `ret` with the length of the message you want to send.

```
const char *msg = "HTTP/1.1 ...";
ret = strlen(msg);
write(fd, msg, ret);
```

Comment: Dang, 2 days of debugging for this stupid mistake. Guess I just needed to sleep and another set of good eyes! Thanks :)